# window.print not working anymore

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php page with this javascript:

```
function printStuff($stuffdetails) {
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
window.print();
window.location = "<?=$stuffdetails['redirect']?>";
</script>
```

Nothing gets printed.
When I remove

`window.location = "<?=$stuffdetails['redirect']?>";`

the print works.
any idea whats going wrong?
thanks!

I found the solution myself:

```
    window.print();
    setTimeout (function() {delayRedirect();},100);

    function delayRedirect()
    {window.location.href = "<?=$stuffdetails['redirect']?>";}
```

with a small timeout everything works

Comment: Note: `LANGUAGE="JavaScript"` is a bit old school

Comment: How do you call printStuff?

Comment: i have a main php page where the printStuff function is called: printStuff($stuffdetails).  the printstuff function is in a function.php page which is included in the main php page